# Why is Datastax cassandra sparkContext is selecting 124 rows in RDD when trying to select only single row through limit 1

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, datastax

I am using datastax cassandra sparkContext(sc) and running following scala code :

```
val table = sc.cassandraTable("database_name", "table_name")
val rdd = table.limit(1)
rdd.count
```

The above is printing 124, which means 124 records are selected, even when the limit given as parameter is 1. Similarly on table.limit(2) is giving 248 rows. Is there a specific reason for a 124 multiplier, or am I missing something?

Comment: Does cassandra have a concept of regions similar to HBase or tablets like Accumulo? If it does you might be getting 1 result from each split within the table you're selecting from.

Comment: It seems like a possible explanation, but I am assuming, the datastax cassandra spark connector library should have addressed this, as the caller of method is explicitly mentioning limit 1. If this is the case, how can I actually select single row.

Comment: Have you tried `take(1)` instead of `limit(1)` ?

Comment: Yeah, take(1) solves selecting fixed number of rows with return type as Array.